# ASP.NET when form onsubmit called DOM elements disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onsubmit

I have simple Html.BeginForm with some data, and i want to check some condition using onsubmit() javascript function when user clicked "submit" button, before form will be send. And when this condition is false, I want to stop reloading page, just don't send my form to POST method. This is working fine, bit I met a problem, because **DOM elements which I create in onsubmit() method disappear**:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", **onsubmit=" return registerValidation()"**}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "emailVal"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email,"", new { @class = "validation-error-white", @id="emailValidation"})

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block add-item-button-text" value="Zarejestruj" />

    }


<script type="text/javascript">

   function registerValidation() {

            var validForm = validateRegisterForm(email, login);
            if (!validForm) {
                $('#emailValidation').append('Those email already exists! Take another one');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
  </script>
```

So when I want to return false, and do not send form, text that I append to validation-div that says what's wrong disappear - it's not what I want to achieve, because it's very small period of time and user cannot even notice that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually trigger the button click event. Make sure ***type*** is ***button***.

*You do not need `**onsubmit=" return registerValidation()"**`*

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" ... />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        // Trigger btnSubmit button's click event, when enter key is pressed.
        // If you do not want that feature, you can ignore this. 
        $("form").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                $("#btnSubmit").click();
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            // Do something, then submit the form
            $("form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Anyway, why input type must be a button here, not submit?
And can I use onclick() instead of click(), and call that in button definition I mean like:  
 <input type="button"  onclick="someFun()"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block add-item-button-text" value="Zarejestruj" /

Comment: `type="button"` won't submit the form. `$("#btnSubmit").click` is jQuery way of attaching an event basically same as `onclick="someFun()"`, but it is a prefer method if you use jQuery.